# Google Analytics Reporting API v4 returns incomplete data, only 10001 rows

Tags: c#, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I use Google Analytics Reporting API v4 for downloading data. In some calls the API returns two pages of data when the endpoint

`https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet`

is called. The first returned page has 10000 rows while the second page has only 1 row. The total of returned rows is therefore 10001. I assume the returned data is incomplete, because the number of sessions and conversions displayed in the web platform is higher then in the data returned over API.

What could be the reason for incomplete data? Is there a workaround?

This is the query object:

```
var obj = new
{
    reportRequests = new[] { new
    {
        viewId = viewCodeWithGaPrefix,
        dateRanges = new[] { new
        {
            startDate = queryStartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            endDate = queryEndDate.AddMinutes(-1.0).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        }},
        metrics = (from m in _parameters.Metrics select new { expression = m }).ToArray(),
        dimensions = (from d in dimensions select new { name = d }).ToArray(),
        orderBys = (from o in _parameters.Sort.Split(',') select new { fieldName = o.TrimStart('-'), sortOrder = o.StartsWith("-") ? "DESCENDING" : "ASCENDING" }).ToArray(),
        samplingLevel = "LARGE",
        segments = new [] { new { segmentId = _parameters.Segment } }.Take(_parameters.Segment == null ? 0 : 1).ToArray(),
        filtersExpression = filters ?? string.Empty,
        dimensionFilterClauses = _parameters.DimensionFilterClauses,
        includeEmptyRows = true,
        pageToken = pageToken ?? string.Empty,
        pageSize = 100000
    }}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

"Google Analytics limits by default the number of rows you can request to 10,000"

"The pageToken field is a token that Google will give you in your API response to indicate that this specific request you are sending is a continuation of a previous uncompleted request."

[Full article is here](https://medium.com/analytics-for-humans/a-cheat-sheet-for-mastering-google-analytics-api-requests-39d36e0f3a4a)